# SSRS report parameters not being passed through, work fine when hard coded

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, parameter-passing, sql-server-profiler

I am using Sql server 2017 and visual studio 2019.

I created a report in SSRS and initially used a stored procedure with a single parameter @Date in it and used the data explorer section to set up the required data sources etc and when challenged for the parameter I put in a date but the report returns blank. I can run the same sp in SSMS fine. I can hard code the date either directly in the WHERE clause or in declaration of the variable and it also then runs fine. I tried a number of things around date formats but I don't need to include the detail of that because I started over and wrote a simple query

```
SELECT id, date FROM [production].[dbo].[products] WHERE id = 10
```

This runs fine and the report in which I have placed a table containing just the two fields is populated with the correct data.

I replace the WHERE id = 10 with

```
WHERE id = @productid
```

...and declare the variable. I run the report and put in the id 10 and the report returns blank.

So, the issue with the initial stored procedure and date is just a more complicated version of this simple example, but in both cases the report parameter does not seem to be being passed through. I have summised as much by using Sql profiler. Looking at where I would expect the parameter to be passed in it instead says N'%'. Now I am not entirely sure what that means but on using the profiler when hard coding the id in,  I can see that the id parameter is passed as N'10'.

I am not sure where I am going wrong. I have dumbed it down to a simple query. It contains a parameter. The parameter is declared and can be inspected in data explorer. It is challenged for and then provided but does not seem to get any further. Yet hard coding the same id in either via the WHERE clause or via the parameter declaration works fine.

Am I missing something?

I created a simple sp to illustrated my issue using the simple example:

```
USE [Production]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_getproduct]
@productid INT = NULL
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT id, date
FROM Production.dbo.Product
WHERE id = @productid

END
```

This is tabbed properly by the way, it is just not showing here. If I use this sp within an ssrs report and run it I get nothing. If I amend the line @productid INT = NULL to be @productid INT = 10 then the report runs fine. I can't see how to post photos of the parameter setup in SSRS but when I add the sp, refresh fields, check the parameter section it is there and is in as [@productid]...I tried it without square brackets but that made no difference

Comment: I think you need to post some images showing the properties of the parameters and the query. Very hard to comment from a description.

Comment: Did you declare the "id" parameter for your stored procedure like `@ID varchar ` by any chance? That is, you did not define a maximum length for the datatype?

Comment: If your SP is combining the parameter in a string, you'd need to escape the string and add the parameter like `'''WHERE id = ''' + @productid + '''` or so. More detail on what you're doing in the SP is prob needed.

Comment: Hi in the simple example I declared it as an int so @productid INT

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the quotes around your code are not actually in your dataset query, if they are then remove them.

Also, in a dataset query, you should **not** declare the parameter that you are passing in from SSRS, sql 'scripts' as your datasource behave differently then calling a stored proc.

So you dataset query should just be

```
SELECT id, date FROM [production].[dbo].[products] WHERE id = @productid
```

No quotes, no declaration or `@productid`.

If your productid parameter allows multiple values then change the where clause like this

```
SELECT id, date FROM [production].[dbo].[products] WHERE id IN(@productid)
```

Comment: Hi sorry the quotes aren't in my original script, I was told to use three quotes to show code and that's what I did so not sure how those quotes appeared like that, so do you mean that I shouldn't be declaring the parameters in the sp? In the case of the simple script example I gave it says I have to declare the parameter in SSRS via an error message

Comment: If there is more info I can give or anything I can do to help get an answer I will. This has fixed me for too many hours

Comment: If you are using a Stored Proc, then you write the SP as normal including declarations, then you call the SP with its parameter(s) from SSRS. If you are just writing a script directly in the dataset query, then any parameters passed to the script must **not** be declared. If this does not help, post the output from the profiler based on your simple example and that might help narrow it down. FYI: For formatting code, highlight the text and click the Code format button on the top toolbar, alternatively, start the line with 4 spaces and it will formatted as text.

Comment: Thanks for your continued help Alan, I have edited the question slightly using the simple example to show how using an sp with a parameter doesn't work but replacing the parameter with the same id in the sp does...I don't understand that. Also profiler for both just shows the name of the sp being called against Batchstarting and Batchcompleted

Comment: I can't remember what bits you need to turn on in the profiler but you should be able to see the actual statement being passed and the parameter value (you mentioned you saw `N'10` so that might be the bit that's important.